# How to change XML parent tags

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Say I have an xml file like so:

```
<ArrayOfInternetProxy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <InternetProxy>
    <ProxyName />
    <ProxyIP>23.19.34.127:8800</ProxyIP>
    <Username />
    <Password />
  </InternetProxy>
</ArrayOfInternetProxy>
```

There where many more `<InternetProxy>` in the xml file, but I removed them for clarity.

`<InternetProxy>` representes an object in my program, while `<ArrayOfInternetProxy>` represents an array of said object.

How can I change the tags `<ArrayOfInternetProxy>` and `<InternetProxy>` to be whatever I like?

I managed to change the attributes by using:

```
    [XmlElement("ProxyName")]
    public string ProxyName { get; set; }
```

But this doesn't work on the other tags.

Thanks.

My class:

```
public class InternetProxy //I want to change this in the xml output
{
    [XmlElement("ProxyName")]
    public string ProxyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ProxyIP")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Here is what I tried, why doesn't this work for me??

```
[XmlElement("Proxies")]
[XmlArray("Proxies")]
List<InternetProxy> proxies;
```

Comment: Can you provide your class and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like:

```
[XmlArray("Proxies")]
public InternetProxy[] InternetProxy
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

To control how it's serialized you can apply following attributes:

- `XmlArrayAttribute`: it'll change the name of the array (your actual `ArrayOfInternetProxy`).
- `XmlArrayItemAttribute`: it'll change the name of the array items (your actual `InternetProxy`).

If you serialize directly your array (so you don't have such property with the array) you should apply XmlType attribute, like:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="Proxies")]
public class InternetProxy
{
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.10).aspx for details.

Comment: Does this still work with List? I tried the tags but it still used the default name.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that you can't change the node name this way if the array is the parent node (the outermost array).